# How to remove approval's debug info from build logs

Tags: .net, unit-testing, approval-tests

When I am running approval tests some debug output from approval test gets to my logs. It looks like

`2/15/2016 1:58:48 PM ~000002ms Variable: approvalFrame = ''
2/15/2016 1:58:48 PM ~000025ms Variable: approvalFrame = ''
2/15/2016 1:58:48 PM ~000003ms Variable: approvalFrame = ''
2/15/2016 1:58:48 PM ~000002ms Variable: approvalFrame = '......`

Is there any way to hide it from logs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ApprovalTests uses the SimpleLogger for logging. If you set it to null it won't log to your files. If you want to use the SimpleLogger afterwards, reset it.

```
 ApprovalUtilities.SimpleLogger.Logger.Writer = NullWriter.Instance;
```

To reset

```
Logger.Writer = new MultiWriter(new ConsoleWriter(),new DebugerWriter());
```

There are lot's of other writers of course and you can make your own composites or very own versions as well.

Happy Testing!

Comment: @llewellyn_falco thanks -- one more question then. Where is the best place to put that code? Kind of Approvals bootstrapper or something?

Comment: good question. I usually have a sort of setup thing / config thing for most of my projects.
If it's bothersome you could make a base test class, or sneak it into a custom reporter initializer. 
There isn't really a approvals bootstrapper at the moment.